# New to python 3 and having problems accessing dictionary values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a simple login page using information stored in the dictionary. Everytime I enter the correct user name and password combination it falls back to the else statement- "sorry credentials not found in database". What am I doing wrong?

```
acc={"t":"000", "b":"123", "r":"456"}
p=input ("enter account name :")
pp=input ("enter account password :")
if p==dict.keys(acc) and pp==dict.values(acc):
 print ("access granted")
else:
 print ("sorry credentials not found in database")
```

Comment: 1. Python keywords are lowercase 2. This is not how `keys()` and `values()` work.

Comment: `if p in dict.keys() and dict[p]==pp` is the correct check here.

Comment: Suggestion1 will be to use if `pp == acc.get(p,"some default value")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keys` and `values` method return sequences of *all* keys and values, respectively. Neither will be equal to a single key or value.

```
if p in acc and pp == acc[p]:
    print("access granted")
else:
    print("sorry credentials not found in database")
```

Tangentially, `dict.keys(acc)` is a rather stilted way of writing `acc.keys()` (and likewise for `acc.values()`).

Comment: That works! Thanks, I'm new to coding and I'm just experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

`dict.keys(acc)` (same as `acc.keys()`) gives you a list of all dictionary keys. A single login name is never equal to a list. What you need is to check if the login name `P` is in the dictionary and its value matches the stored password:

```
if acc.get(P, None) == Pp:
```

By the way, both `P` and `Pp` are bad identifiers.

Comment: Yes I know I should have used better identifiers but this is just a little bit of code I wanted to write, not a whole project. What is "None" for in your code?

Comment: `None` is a value returned when the key is not found in the dictionary ("no such account"). Since the password is never equal to `None`, the condition would be false.

Answer (score -1):

Examine the return value of `dict.keys(acc)`.

```
>>> acc = {"t":"000", "b":"123", "r":"456"}
>>> P = input ("enter account name : ")
Tiddles
>>> p
'Tiddles'
>>> dict.keys(acc)
dict_keys(['t', 'b', 'r'])
>>> p == dict.keys(acc)
False
```

It's always going to be False?

You probably want something like this:

```
>>> acc = {"username": "Tiddles", "password": "12345"}
>>> p = input("enter account name: ")
Tiddles
>>> acc['username'] == p
True
```